# Node.JS run routes synchronously

Tags: node.js, express, routes

In this example, I have two routes - the first is a Get route and the second is a Post route. I want the information gathered in the get route to be included in the post route. I tried using .then and some basic boolean if logic but I cannot get these routes to run synchronously.

```
leadFormObj = {};
$.get("/getID/"+leadFormObj.parentEmail, function(event){
        console.log("getting an ID");
        console.log(event[0].id);
        leadFormObj.parentID = event[0].id;

    });
    console.log(leadFormObj);
    $.post("/addChild", leadFormObj, function(data) {
        console.log(leadFormObj);
        console.log("sent");
    });
```

In the example above, I have a standard object (i've shown it blank in this example). The first get route will run and pass in a new key value pair to the object. I then want to pass this updated object to the post route but I'm not sure how to do this.

Would I use nested routes to do this?

Thanks!

Comment: What you are trying to do doesn't make sense. If you want `/getID/` to run first and `/addChild` second, what happens if someone navigates to `/addChild` first?

Comment: That's true - they could accidentally do that. I have a button on click sending the user to the both of those routes at the same time. Is there a better way to set it up?

Comment: then just make it one route!

Comment: If you want there to be server state that is set by one request and then used in a following request, you have to create a server-side session and store the state in the session so you can access it when the subsequent requests from the same client arrive.  But, usually, you would fetch some info with one request into the client and then include appropriate info with the next request that tells the server what to do with the next request.

Comment: FYI, `$.get()` and `$.post()` are client requests, not routes.  If you want help with your server side routes, then you need to show us the server side code.  But, if this is just two successive requests from the client, then just make one route on the server that handles the whole operation with just one client request - that's a lot more efficient.

Comment: @jfriend00 you're the man, thanks so much for clarifying that for me!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why don't you put the post request inside the callback of the get request

```
$.get("/getID/"+leadFormObj.parentEmail, function(data){
    $.post("/addChild", {parentID: data[0].id}, function(data) {
      console.log("sent");
    });
});
```